# Login jsp error in DWP (Eclipse)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

i've to build a dynamic web project in Eclipse(Moon) with Tomcat 7.0 and mysql database (5.1). I've created a java class for users, a connector java class between jsp and mysql and the jsp pages with a login/registration forms.

This is the user.java class:

```
package cop;
public class Company {
    public String name = "";
    public String username = "";
    public String password = "";
    public String email = "";
    public String country = "";
    public String address = "";  
    public Company(String username, String password){
        this.username = username;
        this.password= password;
    }
}
```

This is the connector .java class:

```
public static Company DB_login1(String user, String pass){

    Company co = null;

try{

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/Mysql?user=root&password=root");


    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT username "
                                                    + "FROM Companies "
                                                    + "WHERE username = '"+user+"' AND password = '"+pass+"'");
    pst.setString(1, user);
    pst.setString(2, pass);

    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()){
        String username =  rs.getString("username");    
        String password =  rs.getString("password");    
        co = new Company(username, password);               
    }
        con.close();
    }

catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Unable to connect to DB");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return co;
```

}

And at last this is the login.jsp:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="cop.*" import="java.util.*"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>

<div id="head">
<title>The Music Shop</title>
</div>
<div id="titles">
 <text id="t1"> The Music Shop </text> <br>
 <text id="t2"> The new way of buying is here </text>
</div>



<div id="login">
    <form id="login_form" action="company-login.jsp" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <ul>
            <li> <label for="user">  Username </label>
            <input type="text" name="user" required></input></li>
            <li> <label for="pass">  Password </label>
            <input type="text" name="pass" required></input></li>
            <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"> </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>

<% String user = request.getParameter("user");
   String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

   Company co = Dbcon.DB_login1(user , pass);

   if (co == null){
       response.sendRedirect("home.jsp?err=1");
       }
   else{
       response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
   }
%>
```

When i run the jsp page on Tomcat, immediately it redirects me to the "home.jsp?err=1" page, and it doesn't display the html page. Has anyone any suggestions to fix it? 
Thanks in regard.

Comment: `Company DB_login1()` returns `null`.

Comment: @firstofthebadones edit the code in the question not the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   String user = request.getParameter("user");
   String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

   Company co = Dbcon.DB_login1(user , pass);

   if (co == null){
       response.sendRedirect("home.jsp?err=1");
       }
   else{
       response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
   }
```

if you run your jsp page without passing any parameters(user,pass) , `Dbcon.DB_login1(user , pass);` will get `null` as both arguments . Your query will not return any results and `co` will remain assigned to `null` and so `Dbcon.DB_login1(user , pass);` returns `null` to your jsp. which then satisfies your if condition and the page gets redirected.

change

```
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT username "
                                                    + "FROM Companies "
                                                    + "WHERE username = '"+user+"' AND password = '"+pass+"'");
```

to

```
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT username "
                                                    + "FROM Companies "
                                                    + "WHERE username = '"+?+"' AND password = '"+?+"'");
```

Comment: Sorry @Ramanlfc i'm at the beginning with java. My purpose is passing to Dbcon.DB_login1(user , pass) user and pass value taken from the jps page by filling the login form.

Comment: i want use them to find a correspondence in mysql db too. Maybe i've done some errors in this way

Comment: @firstofthebadones the scriptlet code in `login.jsp` should be in `company-login.jsp`,

Comment: Oh, a little mistake after all; now it's work! Thanks for fast answers :D

Answer (score 0):

Check your console, there must be some error trace.
Add `System.out.println(e)` as well so that if trace is disabled you can able to see the error in console

```
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Unable to connect to DB");
    System.out.println(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```